# Some Collisions Aren't Working (Actionscript 3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to Actionscript and I'm playing around and testing with collisions. I have it working okay, but there are platforms where the player can just jump straight up and through and sometimes can walk straight though when coming from the right.

Here's my .fla file so you can test it and see the code:

http://www.mediafire.com/?sspz4grjilvvdd6

I think it's because of the I've used points. How can I fix this?

Also, is it true using hitTestObject can sometimes detect collisions when there isn't actually a collision. That's why I've tried points.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's good you provided a .fla for testing, but you would do best also putting the relevant code in your question. For one, not everyone wants to download a file, starting up Flash and trying it. Secondly, we can't be sure there's no virus in the downloadable file (especially since you have no specific username nor any reputation here)

Comment: Have you considered a [physics engine](http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: For simplicity try defining some rectangles if you only need those kind of collisions. Then check collision by using the Rect.contains(x,y) method. Here's a quick demo: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/20444548/Stack%20Overflow/CollisionDemo.fla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140737/collision-detection-of-sprites-in-actionscript-3-0-flash/10150859#10150859). All you'll need is to put your objects inside movieclips and name them.