# Why doesn't this function work on different resolution?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection, resolution

I was searching for a pixel level collision detection because `hitTestObject` and `hitTestPoint` are not very efficient for irregular shapes.

I found out this link : [Collision Detection of Sprites in Actionscript 3.0 Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140737/collision-detection-of-sprites-in-actionscript-3-0-flash)

The link contains a function that detect collision of irregular movie clips and It works very well. It has only one issue, It doesn't work on different resolution.

For example, I want to work on full screen mood so I've typed the following code :

```
import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN ;
```

When the .SWF file is working on full screen, The function doesn't work.

When I press "Esc" on keyboard to exit full screen mood, The function works properly.

Also, If I resized the window of the .SWF file, The function doesn't work again !!

It is a great function, easy to use, and I really need it.. but I don't know why it does this strange behavior !!

The function is :

```
trace("Collided: " + (areaOfCollision(mc1, mc2) != null));
trace("Where: " + areaOfCollision(mc1, mc2));

function areaOfCollision(object1:DisplayObject, object2:DisplayObject, tolerance:int = 255):Rectangle {
    if (object1.hitTestObject(object2)) {
        var limits1:Rectangle = object1.getBounds(object1.parent);
        var limits2:Rectangle = object2.getBounds(object2.parent);
        var limits:Rectangle = limits1.intersection(limits2);
        limits.x = Math.floor(limits.x);
        limits.y = Math.floor(limits.y);
        limits.width = Math.ceil(limits.width);
        limits.height = Math.ceil(limits.height);
        if (limits.width < 1 || limits.height < 1) return null;

        var image:BitmapData = new BitmapData(limits.width, limits.height, false);
        var matrix:Matrix = object1.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
        matrix.translate(-limits.left, -limits.top);
        image.draw(object1, matrix, new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 255, -255, -255, tolerance));
        matrix = object2.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
        matrix.translate(-limits.left, -limits.top);
        image.draw(object2, matrix, new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 255, 255, 255, tolerance), BlendMode.DIFFERENCE);

        var intersection:Rectangle = image.getColorBoundsRect(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFF00FFFF);
        if (intersection.width == 0) return null;
        intersection.offset(limits.left, limits.top);
        return intersection;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Update :** I made a simple trial project to test the function but the problem still exists. In the project, you will find two stars. one of them can be dragged. when the two stars collide with each other, a text will appear. but when I re-size the window to make it larger, the text doesn't appear at all !!
here is the link :

http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g43d4a989bccefabb99964751142bbc6fb6af8d9e4

Comment: I'm not sure what else is going on with you project but I just tried the collision method and it works both on fullscreen and normal mode.

Comment: @Dimitris I've made a new test project to know if the problem is due to my main project or due to the function. but the problem still exists. If you want to see my codes, check the update of this question and you can download the file.

Comment: @Dimitris In this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140737/collision-detection-of-sprites-in-actionscript-3-0-flash
tziuka has wrote a comment on the best answer and I think he refers to the same issue.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Oh, I don't have a good graphics card. it's 384 MB Intel ( Not Nvidia ). 
can it cause the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies on the drawing of the bitmaps that is required for the collision.

```
var matrix:Matrix = object1.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
matrix.translate(-limits.left, -limits.top);
```

The above code works only of the `stage.scaleMode` is equal to `StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE`

So we need to calculate the correct matrix and supply it to the `BitmapData` `draw` method.

So this
`image.draw(object1, matrix, new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 255, -255, -255, tolerance));`

should become

`image.draw(object1, getCorrectMatrix(object1, limits), new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 255, -255, -255, tolerance));`

---

```
function getCorrectMatrix(object:DisplayObject, hitRectangle:Rectangle):Matrix {

    // get the concatenated matrix from the root (global stage)
    var rootConcatenatedMatrix : Matrix = target.root.transform.concatenatedMatrix;

    // convert the target's 0,0 position to global position
    var localToGlobal:Point = object.localToGlobal( new Point() );
    // get the concatenatedMatrix from the target
    var matrix:Matrix = object.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
    // translate the x,y coordinates, 
    matrix.tx = localToGlobal.x - hitRectangle.x;
    matrix.ty = localToGlobal.y - hitRectangle.y;

    // this is important!!
    // the 'a' parameter of the matrix is the value that affects the x position when scaling or rotating.
    // the 'd' parameter of the matrix is the value that affects the y position when scaling or rotating.
    // We devide these values from our matrix and the rootConcatenated matrix to position our final matrix correctly.
    matrix.a = matrix.a / rootConcatenatedMatrix.a;
    //matrix.d = matrix.d / rootConcatenatedMatrix.d;

    return matrix;
}
```

This might help to figure out what is happening on the collision function.

Create an empty bitmap and add it to the stage.

```
var collisionDrawingHelper:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
addChild(collisionDrawingHelper);
```

then inside the `areaOfCollision` function, after the drawing of the image variable add this `collisionDrawingHelper.bitmapData = image`

```
...
matrix = object2.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
matrix.translate(-limits.left, -limits.top);
image.draw(object2, matrix, new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 255, 255, 255, tolerance), BlendMode.DIFFERENCE);

collisionDrawingHelper.bitmapData = image;

var intersection:Rectangle = image.getColorBoundsRect(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFF00FFFF);

...
```

Comment: That's a wonderful solution. It is what I really need ... Thank you very much...  I've made some small changes because I could see the child called "collisionDrawingHelper"  on the screen
so I typed this code :
collisionDrawingHelper.visible = false ;

Comment: Also, I changed the code for object2 like the way you told me for object1




image.draw(object2, getCorrectMatrix(object2, limits), new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 255, 255, 255, tolerance), BlendMode.DIFFERENCE);

Comment: Thank you very much once again, you helped me a lot and you deserve more than the best answer :) :)